# RGB Curves Displacement Symmetry

Tags: node-editor, procedural, vector

I'm new to vector displacement. I'm trying to get a symmetric displacement through RGB Curves but I can't get it to work. I'm trying to get a guitar shape.

This is my setup so far. As you can see, I achieved symmetry by duplicating the RGB curve and mixing them but utterly broke the mesh doing so.
Is there a better way to acheve what I'm trying to do ?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Added a bigger node tree picture

[image: Node Tree]

[image: Resulting mesh]

Comment: Hello. The node tree is not readable (too small and incomplete), also we do not know what you are trying to do, what it the undisplaced mesh is, etc...

Comment: Added a better picture and my goal (a guitar soundboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the rgb curves the mesh is collapsing on itself. The solution I found was to shift the curves left and right with respectively an add and a subtract node.

[image: rgb curve shift]